# JQuery combine Attribute with selector and without

Tags: jquery

```
$('div[id^="start_with"] and not [id$="end_with"]').each(function () {
    //TO DO
});
```

How to combine multiple selectors, if some of them is NOT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) immediately(without any spaces) following the first attribute condition

```
$('div[id^="start_with"]:not([id$="end_with"])').each(function () {
    //TO DO
});
```